# Missing jade statue on the Waterfront

Tags: sleeping-dogs

I've collected all the other statues - and in fact even remember collecting this one in the Popstar Lead #3 mission, but somehow the "return the statue" mission never came up for that statue. Now, I can neither "return the statue", nor can I find it on the boat in Waterfront. The map shows the statue as a collectible, but when I get close to it the icon disappears.

How do I reset it?

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution for this?

Comment: Far as I remember, no, not for that save :( Turns out I did the order of missions wrong or something, and I wasn't going to start another save to fix it :)

Comment: I don't remember which statue was were, but after I found & returned the tenth statue, suddenly the school's entrance lit up again, allowing me to return the last statue that I seem to have picked up before. Maybe the order in which they are returned is somehow fixed. But maybe it's just a bug and you actually already have the statue and just need to manually return it without the quest showing up on the map